# react-native-google-mobile-ads dont work with mediation, Meta, AdColony And Unity Ads

Tags: android, react-native, react-native-google-mobile-ads

I'm facing several issues when trying to mediate with Meta Audience Network, Adcolony and Unity Ads.
On Faebook with bidding it gives the error of 'No Ad Config'
In Unity Ads and Adcolony with waterfall gives the error:
Adcolony SDK requires an Activity context to initialize Ads
Unity Ads require an Activity context to load Ads

I'm using the latest version of google mobile ads:

```
"react-native-google-mobile-ads": "^8.2.2",
```

I put everything right in app/build.gradle

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:21.3.0'
implementation 'com.google.ads.mediation:facebook:6.12.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.ads.mediation:adcolony:4.8.0.0'
implementation 'com.unity3d.ads:unity-ads:4.5.0'
implementation 'com.google.ads.mediation:unity:4.5.0.0'
```

Even the ad inspection shows that everything is correct

I've tried to do several things and several tests but without success!

Note: All ads I'm trying to load are in test mode, I've already configured the device on Meta, Unity and AdColony platforms if activated in placement

Comment: Any solution @Adriano Ernesto?

Comment: Apologies for the delay.
I don't know what I did, so far I still don't understand anything, it has been working on my phone where the app is under test. Other phones do not.

In addition to the Audiece Network goal needs to be logged in the native app to show ads I think other networks also need it.

Sorry but I don't know the right one!

Answer (score 0):

I would like to share that I succesfully implemented AdMob Mediation using React Native library react-native-google-mobile-ads.

Here's a checklist of what to do (code-wise):

- Update the Info.plist adding the SKAdNetworkItems keys (there are a
  lot) for iOS.
- Add AppLovinSDK and Chartboost input/output Paths to project.pbxproj
  for iOS.
- Adds Pods for ‘GoogleMobileAdsMediationAppLovin’,
  ‘GoogleMobileAdsMediationChartboost’,
  ‘GoogleMobileAdsMediationFyber’, ‘GoogleMobileAdsMediationIronSource’
  and ‘GoogleMobileAdsMediationFacebook’ on iOS.
- Add “applovin.sdk.key” metadata to AndroidManifest.xml on Android
- Add repositories { maven { url 'https://android-sdk.is.com/' } maven
  { url 'https://cboost.jfrog.io/artifactory/chartboost-ads/' } } to
  build.gradle on Android
- Add implementations of applovin, facebook, ironsource, chartboost and
  fyber to build.gradle on Android

So for the tutorials, look for mediation for the following adapters:

- AppLovin
- ChartBoost
- IronSource
- Fyber
- Facebook

Check here and follow the steps:

https://developers.google.com/admob/android/choose-networks
https://developers.google.com/admob/ios/choose-networks